# UITableViewController cells disappear if inside a UIScrollView

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiscrollview

This is my storyboard:

[image: Storyboard]

My scrollView is contains 3 NavigationController(containing BubbleListController which is a sort of Table view). These 3 views are put one aside the other and this is the code:

ioBubbleListController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ioBubbleListController : UITableViewController {
    NSDictionary *bubbles;
}

@end
```

**ioBubbleListController.m**

```
#import "ioBubbleListController.h"

@interface ioBubbleListController ()
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDictionary *bubbles;

@end

@implementation ioBubbleListController
@synthesize bubbles;

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

#pragma mark - View lifecycle

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.bubbles = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"bubbles" ofType:@"plist"]];

    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations.
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
}


#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return [self.bubbles count];
}

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [[self.bubbles allKeys] objectAtIndex:section];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSString *continent = [self tableView:tableView titleForHeaderInSection:section];
    return [[self.bubbles valueForKey:continent] count];
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CountryCell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    // Configure the cell...
    NSString *continent = [self tableView:tableView titleForHeaderInSection:indexPath.section];
    NSString *country = [[self.bubbles valueForKey:continent] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.textLabel.text = country;

    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;

    return cell;
}

#pragma mark - Table view delegate

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *continent = [self tableView:tableView titleForHeaderInSection:indexPath.section];
    NSString *country = [[self.bubbles valueForKey:continent] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil
                                                    message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"You selected %@!", country]
                                                   delegate:nil
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                          otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];

    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
}

@end
```

This is my **ioUIPager** which puts one BubbleList aside the other

```
#import "ioUIPager.h"

@implementation ioUIPager

@synthesize scrollView;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self scrollView].contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.scrollView.frame.size.width * 3, self.scrollView.frame.size.height);


    UIStoryboard *sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard_iPhone" bundle:nil];


    // View1
    UITableViewController *view1 = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"BubblesList"];

    CGRect frame1;
    frame1.origin.x = self.scrollView.frame.size.width * 0;
    frame1.origin.y = 0;
    frame1.size = self.scrollView.frame.size;

    [self.scrollView addSubview:view1.view];
    view1.view.frame = frame1;
    view1.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];

    // View2
    UIViewController *view2 = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"BubblesList"];

    CGRect frame2;
    frame2.origin.x = self.scrollView.frame.size.width * 1;
    frame2.origin.y = 0;
    frame2.size = self.scrollView.frame.size;

    [self.scrollView addSubview:view2.view];
    view2.view.frame = frame2;
    view2.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

    // View2
    UIViewController *view3 = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"BubblesList"];

    CGRect frame3;
    frame3.origin.x = self.scrollView.frame.size.width * 2;
    frame3.origin.y = 0;
    frame3.size = self.scrollView.frame.size;

    [self.scrollView addSubview:view3.view];
    view3.view.frame = frame3;


}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
    self.scrollView = nil;
}

//- (void)dealloc {
//    [scrollView release];
//    [super dealloc];
//}

@end
```

Everything is rendered fine at first look, however any gesture/touch/tap I do on the UITableView/ioBubbleList, every cell disappears like this:

[image]
[image]

If from the storyboard I start from the navigator controller, then everything works fine. Any hint?

Comment: Did you solve this issue in the end?

Answer (score 3):

I solved this.

My issue was I was not keeping a reference of the UITableViewControllers and UITableViews I was adding inside the UIScrollView.

I just initialized and NSMutableArray and saved the UITableViewControllers the way I added the UITableViews into the UIScrollView.

EDIT

After some research I found that there is a smarter/better way to do this. Instead of keeping the instance inside our own array we should add the view controllers as childs to the container view controller (the UIViewController with the UIScrollView).

Here the explanation from apple docs:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers.html

Here the code I used:

`self.addChildViewController(tableViewController)`
`self.scrollView.addSubview(tableViewController.view)`
`tableViewController.didMoveToParentViewController(self)`

Saving the tableViewControllers just in an array cannot keep track of the hierarchy inside the content view controller. This means that if we want to access the content view controller from the table view controllers we cannot. And several errors could happen with the UINavigationController if we are using it.